# Where is positive or negative the function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\left(\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}\right)^2$ over the set $[0,2\pi]$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, graphing-functions, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

If I am right it is standard to prove that $$\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\left(\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}\right)^2dx=\frac{\pi}{\zeta(3)}\tag{1}$$
using uniform convergence, where $\mu(n)$ denotes the Möbius function (the definition for example from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html)), and $\zeta(s)$ the Riemann's zeta. I wondered this question when I was refreshing the first example (Fourier) of page 63 from [1].

I am interested to know more about the function in the integrand.

> **Question.** Can you prove an interval $\mathcal{I}\subset[0,2\pi]$ where $$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\left(\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}\right)^2\tag{2}$$
>   is positive or well negative? **Many thanks.**

I think that determine with accuracy the roots of such function, and thus the subintervals (of $[0,2\pi]$) where our function is negative or positive is very difficult, thus I am asking about what work can be done.

My question was inspired in the plot for a toy model of our function $(2)$, see this code

`plot sum  MoebiusMu(n)/n (cos(nx)/n)^2, from n=1 to 1000, 0<x<2pi`

instead of  `plot sum 1/n (cos(nx)/n)^2, from n=1 to 1000, 0<x<2pi` **or** `plot sum (-1)^n/n (cos(nx)/n)^2, from n=1 to 1000, 0<x<2pi` using [Wolfram Alpha online calculator.](https://www.wolframalpha.com)

### References:

[1] Jack D’Aurizio, *Superior Mathematics from an Elementary point of view*, course notes, University of Pisa (2017-2018).

Comment: Only is required the discussion of a subinterval where our function has the same sign, or a point where the sign changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of such subinterval can be found quite easily. By the [Weierstrass M-test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassM-Test.html) the series converges absolutely and [uniformly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_series) in $\left[0,2\pi\right]$, then $f\left(x\right)$ is continuous. So take $x=\pi.$ Then $$f\left(\pi\right)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\mu\left(n\right)}{n^{3}}\cos^{2}\left(n\pi\right)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\mu\left(n\right)}{n^{3}}=\frac{1}{\zeta\left(3\right)}>0$$ then by the [sign preserving property for continuous functions](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/class255/08s1/01s2/H5.pdf) exists and open interval $I$ containing $\pi$ such that $$ f\left(x\right)>0,\,\forall x\in I.$$

Comment: Many thanks, I am going to take a minutes to read also the course notes about continuity because are very good summary.